# Storing references to objects in exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, reference

Is it an antipattern to store references to objects in exceptions?
I'm considering to do so, because I want to have the ability to access these objects later for exceptionhandling-purposes (perhaps in another tier with a higher level of abstraction), e.g. to render a user-friendly message with informations about the context in which the exception was thrown.

I'm not quite sure if there are side-effects, perhaps memory leaks ore something else which I have to know about...

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that it's common for exceptions to be serialized for any number of reasons, and you don't want to drag domain objects into it. Instead, extract the core information that may be useful into immutable properties on the exception class (usually of "simple" types such as `String`, `long`, or `UUID`). It's fine to use the domain objects as parameters to the exception's constructor. I will frequently even use properties when calling `super(message)` (Groovy strings make this easier).

Answer (score 1):

You may provide additional information but do it concise, in example in jdk exists that exceptions that provide additional data about himself. In this example from javadoc [ScriptException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptException.html) you will see additional methods that return line number, column name, etc. In exception constructor all this information passed to instance but not something like whole `ScriptEngine` and you make do something like this. But don't put to exception some heavy weight object and expose them from getters to client and let him do something with this object.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is receiving this object in your Exception constructor, build a friendly message and pass it to the superclass constructor. 
It's never a good idea to show Exception messages for end users, they are only for others developers.